# Javascript high order functions - How do pass a variable from to function to it's parent function

Tags: javascript, variables, currying

I'm trying to solve this algorithm. I think I'm very close.

I need the `seven` function to pass the `a` variable to the `timesFive` function. OR is there a way I can pass the `* 5` operation from timesFive to seven in order to get the desired result?

- I'm not allowed to have variables outside of these two function scopes.
- I can add another argument to timesFive as long as b remains the first argument.

  ```
  function seven(action) {
      var a = 7;

      return action;
  }


  function timesFive(b) {
      console.log(a);  // How can I access "a"?

      return a * 5;
  }


  console.log(seven(timesFive()));    // Desired result: 35
  ```

Comment: Are you *sure* you're required to have the functions in that particular order, `seven(timesFive())`? I'd have expected them to be the other way around

Comment: I have to know what this is for? Who is asking you to write code like this?

Comment: It's likely you have misunderstood what you were asked to accomplish. I assume the goal is to teach you closures, scopes and higher-order function. Either your teacher is providing you with a very bad example, either you did not fully understand the task at hand.

Comment: @soueuls This might not be a great example of closures, but I don't think that's what it's meant to be. It's a fine example of composing functions.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It's not, your proved it with your answer. You either had to remove `b` from the function's signature or just plain ignore it. That's why I assume either the problem could do a better job at teaching higher-order function, either OP did not fully understand the problem.

Comment: @soueuls I agree the OP probably doesn't understand the problem; that's why they are asking the question (which is fine: higher order functions are hard at first).  My point was that the goal is probably not to teach closures, but rather  composing higher order functions.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I am not saying OP should understand higher order functions at first glance, it takes time. I am saying OP probably did not fully understand the question that was asked (or maybe the question is poorly written). In your solution, you remove `b` entirely while OP specifically says it should be kept as first argument. It's obviously possible to just ignore it. I just encourage OP to re-read the problem's statement carefully.

Comment: @soueuls I reread the question and agree the part about `as long as b remains the first argument.` is a little strange.

Answer (score 1):

`timeFive` should return a function and seven should expect a function as a parameter. Then `seven` can simply call the function that `timesFive()` returns (so basically returning the `* 5` operation as you mentioned in your question):

```js
function seven(action) {
    var a = 7;
    return action(a);
}


function timesFive() {
    return (a) => a * 5;
}

console.log(seven(timesFive()));    // Desired result: 35
```

BTW 
You'll often see these kind of exercises written in a way that mimics the functional notation from math, like:

```js
const seven = (action) => action(7);
const timesFive = () => (a) => a * 5;

console.log(seven(timesFive()));    // Desired result: 35
```